# use function pointer stored in vector

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have a vector containing function pointers:

```
vector<double (*)(vector<double>)> dY = {d2x,d2y,dx,dy}
```

in another function, I have a for loop iterating over this vector.

```
for( vector<double>::const_iterator it = dY.begin(); it != dY.end(); ++it){
    vector<double> Y = {0,10,0,10};
    ...
}
```

Now I want to compute d2x(Y),d2y(Y),dx(Y) and dy(Y), but I fail to correclty cast the iterator, so that I can supply the arguments.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Once you get your answer, you should consider modifying your functions and their type to accept `Y` by reference, rather than by copy.

Comment: What errors do you get when you compile?

Comment: Do you really need to cast, can one not simply type `double result = (*it)(Y)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really iterate over the correct vector? The type of `it` in the loop doesn't fit the `dY` vector.

```
for( vector<double (*)(vector<double>)>::const_iterator it = dY.begin(); it != dY.end(); ++it)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- You need the correct type here
```

Once you have a correct iterator, this should work:

```
double result = (*it)(Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

No cast is needed, just dereference the iterator to get the function pointer:

```
double d = (*it)(Y);
```

However, you've declared the wrong iterator type; it should be

```
vector<double (*)(vector<double>)>::const_iterator
```

Since you're using C++11, you can shorten that to `auto` if you like.